# Configuring Google Apps MX Records VestaCP

Tags: gmail, google-apps, vps, mx-record, vesta

Need help configuring Google Apps Gmail MX Records in VestaCP on my VPS.

I want to know which values to put where. Google give just 2 values, 'Priority' and 'Points to'.

[image]

I tried some combinations but VestaCP says values are wrong. Below is the VestaCP Screen to create MX Records.

[image]

Please help me with the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below based on [this](https://vestacp.com/docs/#how-to-configure-srv-records)

```
Domain: xxx.com
Records: *
Type: MX
IP or Value: ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
Priority: 1
```

If records `*` not works, please try `*.xxx.com` instead.

---

And according to [this](https://blog.dnsimple.com/2015/04/common-dns-records/), please make sure your domain is matching a correct A record.

> MX entries must point to a domain, and never point directly to an IP address. If no MX record exists on a domain to which an SMTP server attempts to deliver mail, the server will attempt to deliver the mail to the matching A record

According to GSuite document, please make sure you have cleaned all previous MX records. And also, the setting will not be valid immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Record has to be the same as the domain. Maybe an asterisk may work, but I have it with the domain name for all my clients domains and it works for google apps.

So, for `1  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.`, you try and add the values like this:

```
Record: domain.com.
Type: MX
IP or Value: ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
Priority: 1
```

Repeat for every google mail server.

Don't forget to add a dot `.` at the end of both the **record** (*`domain.com.`*) and the **ip or value** (*`ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.`*) fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's Very simple do like that for all gsuite MX record.

```
Domain (Your required domain name)
XXXX.com

Record (@ creates default domain zone record)
@

Type
MX

IP OR Value
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

Priority (This will change as per IP/value)
1
```

Hope this helps!